# This package does not have flutter_web_plugins in the `dependencies` section of `pubspec.yaml`

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

When publishing my package after adding web support i got this error

```
Package validation found the following error:
* line 9, column 1 of lib/hexcolor_web.dart: This package does not have flutter_web_plugins in the `dependencies` section of `pubspec.yaml`.
    ╷
  9 │ import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';
    │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Write the pubspec.yaml dependencies option

Answer (score 81, accepted):

inside your pubspec.yaml

add this

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_web_plugins:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Both flutter's ofcicial docs (https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/url-strategies#configuring-the-url-strategy) and copilot were not able to help.
You did. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If not findable inside flutter sdk like `collection`(in my case)

you can just add it as a normal package from `pub.dev`

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  collection:
```